# Subtract the html Div tags in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml, dom-manipulation

How we could subtract the div tags from the Html String in python?

For example,
My Html DOM is like

```
 <html>
 <div id ="main">
   <div id = "child1">
     ....(some doms)
   </div>
   <div id="child2">
      .......(some nested dom)
   </div>
 </div>
 </html>
```

In this structure I need to subtract from "div #main" to "div #child2"

```
div "main" - div "child2" = div "child1"
```

,ie I need to get "div #child1" in this way

Why I want this way is,

In terms of "child1" contains the dynamic ads(some dynamic loading contents),it may be present may not be also.I couldn't able to get that content directly using the "child1" id

I have tried it in BeautifulSoup() .**version** = 3.0.7a

```
   >>>div = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('div',{'id':'child1'})
   >>>div
      []
```

Could you please help to fix this with the above requirements?

Comment: What you're looking for is removing the `div` with id=child1 from the original html?

Comment: @jcollado I have to get the   div  with id= "child1" data only to pull.I wanna drop the div child2 from div main.So i could able to get the div child1 to store in my DB.

Comment: Why would you need to "drop" one element in order to be able to extract another? Just use a selector that gets the element you need, and ignore everything else.

Comment: Since you came back on the site I assume you read the answers... please either clarify the question in a way that it can be unambiguously answered or upvote/select as accepted the answers that have been given, if they solve the issue for you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. Are you wanting to get all elements before a certain element?

```
import lxml.html as lh

html = """
<div id="div1">
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
"""

tree = lh.fromstring(html)

for el in tree.xpath("div[@id='div2']/preceding-sibling::div"):
    print el.attrib['id']
```

**Result:**

```
div1
```